# Why are 11 rows affected when adding member to role on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run this command...

```
ALTER ROLE role_name ADD MEMBER [AD\username]
```

...and 11 rows are affected. Is this because multiple system tables have to be updated?

Comment: Do you have 11 tables that could match those rows?

Comment: I'm assuming there are 11 system tables that may be affected, but that is what I'm looking to confirm.

Comment: Maybe you can use `output inserted.*, deleted.*` like you can use with update table statements.

Comment: think that only applies to those four specific commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried looking at data from `sys.database_role_members` as is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-role-members-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It's weird that a DDL statement would affect any rows at all. Normally you just get a `Commands completed successfully.` message. Do you have a DDL trigger in your environment?